# Setting up default `node` executable in linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, path

It is my first attempt to set up project with `JavaScript` tools. According to `README` I need to install and run `yarn`. I am getting this error:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "6.x".
```

It happened (don't ask me how, I know it's bad but I was lazy and was just copying commands from the Internet), that I have two versions of `node` in my system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

```
/usr/bin/node --version
v6.11.4
```

and

```
/usr/local/bin/node --version
v8.6.0
```

The default one is:

```
which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

And I guess I need older version from `/usr/bin/node`.
How can I use by default desired one and maybe delete not needed version without creating more chaos in my system?

Comment: Where did the `/usr/bin/node` one come from?

Comment: @tadman I was following this one
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: You may have two conflicting packages installed. It might be worth removing them both, installing just the one you want, and verifying it's correctly operating.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you uninstall them both so that you can run the installation of one among the two of the Node.JS.

```
rm -r /usr/local/bin/node
rm -r /usr/bin/node
```

Again you can run these `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs` which should remove of the gyp, linux-headers-4.4.0-18-generic etc packages.

Since you're running on Ubuntu Linux, you can install Yarn via our Debian package repository. You will first need to configure the repository:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

Then you can simply:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

This should install `yarn` for you.